# Setting Nested Env Variable in Kubernetes (using helm charts)

Tags: kubernetes-helm

How can we set this as environment variable in helm chart?

```
{ "Services:" {
   "Service1": {
     "BaseUrl": "http://xx",
     "XEndpoint": "/endpoint1"
   },
   "Service2": {
     "BaseUrl": "http://xx",
     "XEndpoint": "/endpoint1"
   }
}
```

I tried setting it like below but is not able to access correctly on the pod

```
env:
  Services__Service1__BaseUrl="http://xx"
  Services__Service1__XEndpoint="/endpoint1"
  Services__Service2__BaseUrl="http://xx"
  Services__Service2__XEndpoint="/endpoint1"
```

Comment: What is the first file?  Are you expecting the entire file content to be embedded in a single environment variable, or trying to replace fields in that file?